# Ruby/Selenium can't receive text

Tags: ruby, selenium, xpath

I'm using the "firepath" Firefox extension to test my xpaths.

Running this xpath:

```
driver.find_elements(:xpath, "//path/a[@class='anytext']").map{|el| el.text}
```

against this anchor:

```
<a class="anytext" href="/any/path/" title="Search for skill">text</a>
```

I received all elements on page as `[string1, string2....]`

With this xpath:

```
driver.find_elements(:xpath, "//path/a[@class='anytext and']").map{|el| el.text}
```

and this anchor:

```
<a class="anytext andmore" href="/any/path/" title="Search for skill" aria-describedby="tooltip">text</a>
```

I received array `[" ", " ", ....]` without text.

I understand that the problem is to do with "aria-describedby" but I dont know what to try next? I tried using different methods but not getting what I need.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple classes so try `contains` and `and` in your xpath instead:

```
driver.find_elements(:xpath, "//path/a[contains(@class, 'anytext') and contains(@class, 'and')]").map{|el| el.text}
```

Conversely you could search by `css selectors`:

```
driver.find_elements(:css, "path a.anytext.and").map{|el| el.text}
```

Comment: Sorry. Probably my information was not enough to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with firebug
This is hidden elements with attribute: 'innerHTML' or 'textContent'

i.e.:

```
driver.find_elements(:css, "path to elements").map{|el| el.attribute('textContent')}
```